# My GMSMarker shows on top left , I want to show it on center objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I want to show my marker on the center of the map but it shows on the top left.

[image: Here is the screenshot of my map with a marker]

Below is my code implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
NSDictionary *userLoc=[kNSUserDefaults objectForKey:@"userLocation"];
mapView_.delegate = self;
CGFloat lat = [[userLoc objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue];
CGFloat lon = [[userLoc objectForKey:@"long"] floatValue];
   
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon);
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid;
marker.map = mapView_;
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon zoom:17];
[mapView_ animateToCameraPosition:camera];
[mapView_ setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid;
mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
mapView_.delegate = self;
mapView_.trafficEnabled = YES;
}
```

Not able to understand what's wrong in my code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would start by a simpler auto layout constraint instead of UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight, and maybe start by fixed height and width to make sure the marker is in the center and then work on the auto layout. Because your code looks good and the only part that could make this happen in my opinion is [mapView_ setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

Comment: you are right, I have not added any view inside my viewcontroller, So I have added one view and adding my mapview inside, and it works.